# Reasons that might rise when submitting a Strip Payment

Tags: python, django

I was making a payment trial for my e-commerce project and it was working perfectly fine before and now all of a sudden when i am using the Credit Card Trial Numbers the payment is getting through and the order is made but I receive a message that an `"A serious Error Occured. We have been notified."` the very last message in the Payment Views. I am trying to figure out what error might lead to this.

Here is the views.py:

```
class PaymentView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # order
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        if order.billing_address:
            context = {
                'order': order,
                'DISPLAY_COUPON_FORM': False
            }
            return render(self.request, "payment.html", context)
        else:
            messages.warning(
                self.request, "You have not added a billing address")
            return redirect("core:checkout")

    # `source` is obtained with Stripe.js; see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges#web-create
    # -token
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        amount = int(order.grand_total() * 100)

        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=amount,  # cents
                currency="usd",
                source=token,
            )
            # create payment
            payment = Payment()
            payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
            payment.user = self.request.user
            payment.amount = order.grand_total()
            payment.save()

            # assign the payment to the order

            order_items = order.items.all()
            order_items.update(ordered=True)
            for item in order_items:
                item.save()

            order.ordered = True
            order.payment = payment
            order.ref_code = create_ref_code()
            order.save()

            messages.success(self.request, "Your Order was Successful ! ")
            # Email when order is made
            template = render_to_string("payment_confirmation_email.html", {'first_name': self.request.user.first_name,
                                                                            'last_name': self.request.user.last_name,
                                                                            'order': order})

            msg = EmailMessage('Thanks for Purchasing', template,
                               settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [self.request.user.email])
            msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
            msg.fail_silently = False
            msg.send()

            # End of the email send
            return render(self.request, "order_completed.html", {'order': order})

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            body = e.json_body
            err = body.get('error', {})
            messages.warning(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
            # Since it's a decline, stripe.error.CardError will be caught
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
            # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
            messages.warning(self.request, "Rate Limit Error")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
            # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            messages.warning(self.request, "Invalid Parameters")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
            # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
            messages.warning(self.request, "Not Authenticated")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
            # Network communication with Stripe failed
            messages.warning(self.request, "Network Error")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            # yourself an email
            messages.warning(
                self.request, "Something went wrong. You were not charged. Please Try Again.")
            return redirect("/")

        except Exception as e:
            # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            # send an email to ourselves
            messages.warning(
                self.request, "A serious Error Occured. We have been notified.")
            return redirect("/")
```

here is the models.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    stripe_charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting an error message `"A serious Error Occured. We have been notified."` the very last message in the Payment Views

Comment: Can you log the actual error exception that's being raised? You're catching all exceptions in that block and the error may not be with stripe but with your own code

Comment: This blanket exception capturing is a bad idea. If an unhandled exception occurs a 500 response that results in an error email would probably be preferable so that you are notified of an actual issue in your application

Comment: @IainShelvington There is no actual error being raised, after the payment is made 2 messages appear, 1st `"Your Order was Successful ! "` and the 2nd message warning is  `"A serious Error Occured. We have been notified."` but from the admin the payment shows it went through although the error message appears.

Comment: You should remove the blanket except block `except Exception as e:` so that actual issues with your application are not hidden. If you don't want to do that add `traceback.print_exc()` to the block so that the error can be found in your logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it would be better to raise an internal server error (500) when unexpected exceptions are raised, since it is reasonable to classify these as bugs that should be fixed once you discover them. This way, you would have a traceback in your server logs, in an email notification to admins, or elsewhere, depending on you logging configuration. To achieve this, simply remove:

```
except Exception as e:
    ...
```

Besides this, having a long `try` statement is bad practice as it leads precisely to the sort of problems you are having: it makes it hard to determine where the error is when you get "A serious Error Occured". I don't know stripe, but I am pretty sure you can exclude most lines from the `try`. I suspect all the exceptions deriving from `stripe.errors` can only be raised at the line below:

```
charge = stripe.Charge.create( ... )
```

If so, it should be the only line within the `try`.

If this is not the case and different lines may raise different errors, use multiple `try` statements. For example, instead of

```
try:
    calculate_a() # may raise ErrorA
    calculate_b() # may raise ErrorB
except ErrorA:
    ...
except ErrorB:
    ...
```

write:

```
try:
    calculate_a() # may raise ErrorA
except ErrorA:
    ...
try:
    calculate_b() # may raise ErrorB
except ErrorB:
    ...
```